# Three of a kind function - Yahtzee

Tags: c

I got back my school assignment where we were asked to create some functions for the Yahtzee game, one of them were the Three of a Kind function. This is the code I wrote and the comment I got was: "You have to be able to check all numbers up to nrOfDieValues." I'm not quite sure how to check up to x numbers.. I tried using two for loops but that did not end up too well as the saving to the array got messed up. Help would be appreciated ^_^

```
int isThreeOfAKind(const int dieValues[], int nrOfDieValues)
{
    int threeOAK, i, x = 0;
    int tOAK[nrOfDievalues];

    for(i = 0; i < nrOfDieValues; i++)
    {
        switch (dieValues[i]
        {
        case 1:
            tOAK[0]++;
            break;
        case 2:
            tOAK[1]++;
            break;
        ....
        ....
        case 6:
            tOAK[5]++;
            break;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < nrOfDieValues; i++)
    {
        if (tOAK[i] >= 3)
        {
           x = i+1;
           threeOAK = 1; 
        }

    }


    if(threeOAK)
    {
        return x;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: `threeOAK` is not initialized.  Change to `int threeOAK = 0`.  `tOAK[]` is not initialized.  Change to `int tOAK[nrOfDievalues] = {0};`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `switch()`, all it does it map a value of `dieValues[]` to an index into  `tOAK[]`, and that mapping is pretty basic:

```
for(i = 0; i < nrOfDieValues; i++)
{
  tOAK[dieValues[i]] += 1;
}
```

This works the same, but assumes all indexes are 0-based.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. When I put this CMD crashes and gives me this: Process returned 255 (0xFF)   execution time : 7.561 s
Press any key to continue.

Comment: @RasmusNordlander note this line in the answer: "This works the same, but assumes all indexes are 0-based." You are probably using values 1-6 for the dice.  Try: `tOAK[dieValues[i]-1] += 1;`

Comment: @Ras you have other loops too. Check that it works there too.  Can you run it in a debugger to see where it crashes?

Comment: @Baldrickk it crashes when I "enable" this line in printScores function: threeOAK = isThreeOfAKind(diceCheck, nrOfDieValues);

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that the dice inputs are 1-6 while the arrays are 0-5, and that even after my comment you are still having the same problem with your loops.

Assuming that the values on the dice are `1` indexed (unlike in Unwind's answer), I've simplified the algorithm in your function. Comments are embedded in the code:

```
#define MaxScore 6 //maximum score on one die is 6

int isThreeOfAKind(const int dieValues[], int nrOfDieValues)
{
    int i;
    int tOAK[MaxScore];

    memset(tOAK, 0, MaxScore);         //initialise to 0

    for(i = 0; i < nrOfDieValues; i++) //go through each of the inputs
    {
       tOAK[dieValues[i]-1]++;         //increment the count of the result
       if (tOAK[dieValues[i]-1]==3)
       {                               //if we have now seen 3 results 
            return dieValues[i];       //of that value, return it. we don't
       }                               //need to process the rest.
    }
   return 0;      //if we haven't found a three of a kind, return 0.
}
```

**Edit:  Ahah! Can't believe I missed this:**

```
int tOAK[nrOfDievalues];
```

This line is a likely culprit.  You are creating an array of the same size as your input.  This will work fine for an input such as: `{1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3}` but will break on, for example: `{6,5,4}`.
What this array *should* be doing is counting the number of times each result appears, which means that you need the same number of cells as possible scores from one input. So in your case, `6`.

What your code was doing however was creating an array of the same size of the input, so when for example, you called `isThreeOfAKind({6},1)` as input, you created an array `tOAK[1]`.
Trying to reference `tOAK[6]` leads to out of bounds access leading to a crash.
I've fixed this in the code above.

*Note, you could change `MaxScore` to make the function work for other games too: e.g. for a hand of cards, set* `MaxScore` *to* `13` *(aces low) or* `14` *(aces high) and it will find a Three of a Kind in that hand too.*

Answer (score 0):

Another issue I can see in your code: seems to me you confuse the number of die values with the number of dice - I don't know how many dice are thrown in the game, so what are possible values of `nrOfDieValues`, but `tOAK` keeps counters for every die value, so it should be declared `tOAK[6]` (for ordinary cubic dice).

By the way, did you remember to initialize the counters to zeros *before* you start counting...?